# softPwm of wiringPi for servo ... where is the problem?

Tags: python, c

I have a Python code which controls an ESC & servo fine. Now, I'm trying to develop a similar code in C language using wiringPi. However, the C codes don't work. The Python & C codes are attached. So, where is the problem?

- I am using pin#11 or GPIO_17, which should be pin#0 on wiringPi.

The working fine Python:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

dc = 5

servo = GPIO.PWM(11,50)
servo.start(10)
print('***Connect Battery & Press ENTER to start')
res = raw_input()
servo.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
print('***Press ENTER to start')
res = raw_input()

print ('increase > a | decrease > z | save Wh > n | set Wh > h|quit > 9')

cycling = True
try:
    while cycling:
        servo.ChangeDutyCycle(dc)
        res = raw_input()
        if res == 'a':
            dc = dc + 0.05
        if res == 'z':
            dc = dc - 0.05
        if res == 'h':
            mymotor.setWh()
        if res == '9':
            cycling = False
finally:
    # shut down cleanly
    servo.stop()
    print ("dc var setting is: ")
    print (dc)


print('***Press ENTER to quit')
res = raw_input()
servo.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

A very simple C code#1 I developed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>


int main(void)
{

if (wiringPiSetup() < 0) return 1;

pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(0, LOW);
softPwmCreate(0, 0, 500);
softPwmWrite(0, 300);

sleep(30000);
return 0;
}
```

Another simple C code#2 :

```
/*
 * test2.c:
 *      Simple test program to test the wiringPi functions
 *      PWM test
 */

#include <wiringPi.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void)
{
  int pin=0 ;
  int l ;

  printf ("Raspberry Pi wiringPi PWM test program\n") ;

  if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    exit (1) ;


    pinMode (pin, OUTPUT) ;
    digitalWrite (pin, LOW) ;


  pinMode (0, PWM_OUTPUT) ;

  for (;;)
  {
    for (l = 0 ; l < 1024 ; ++l)
    {
      pwmWrite (0, l) ;
      printf ("pwm=%i  \n"), l;
      delay (1) ;
    }

    for (l = 1023 ; l >= 0 ; --l)
    {
      pwmWrite (0, l) ;
      printf ("pwm=%i  \n"), l;
      delay (1) ;
    }
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to do all the things in C that you do in the python code that you aren't currently doing in C, e.g. `raw_input()`?

Answer (score 2):

ESCs and servos need precisely timed pulses at 50Hz+.  Generally each pulse will be between 1000µs to 2000µs in length.

Neither wiringPi (unless using the hardware PWM function) nor RPi.GPIO are suitable for driving ESCs/Servos with any degree of accuracy.  They may be ok if your application doesn't mind a lot of jitter (software timed pulses will vary a lot in time).

If you are doing any serious work you need to be using one of the modules which provides hardware (DMA) timed pulses, or use one or both of the hardware PWM channels, or use external hardware.

Servoblaster, RPIO.GPIO (not RPi.GPIO), and my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html),  all provide DMA timed PWM.

Comment: Thank you very much :D Your answer did help alot. I used pigpio library & now I can control both the ESC & servo fine. And it was very simple using the example code that is available at: [link] (http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#GPIO_hardware_hacking)